# Can't access a dependency config in main elixir project

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have a project **world_app** which I have included in **hello_app** as a dependency (I have included it as a local dependency if that's relevant)

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:world_app, path: "../world_app"}
  ]
end
```

The **world_app** has a config.exs that has this configuration

```
config :world_app, some_config: "config_string"
```

My problem arises when I try to get the config variable defined in **world_app** in **hello_app** (I ran iex -S mix in hello_app)

```
iex(1)> Application.get_all_env(:world_app)
[included_applications: []]

iex(2)> Application.get_env(:world_app, :some_config)
nil
```

However, when I do the same thing in **world_app** I can see the variables

```
iex(1)> Application.get_all_env(:world_app)
[some_config: "config_string", included_applications: []]

iex(2)> Application.get_env(:world_app, :some_config)
"config_string"
```

I've always been under the impression that I could access a dependency's config from the parent application; am I missing something crucial here?

I'm using Elixir 1.5.3 and erlang 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configurations of dependencies are not automatically imported. In [umbrella projects](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-projects.html#umbrella-projects), all children see each other's configuration because the root config contains this magical line:

```
import_config "../apps/*/config/config.exs"
```

which imports all configuration files of all its children, and conversely, all its children are pointing to the root config file in `mix.exs`:

```
defmodule ChildProject.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      (...)
      config_path: "../../config/config.exs",
      (...)
    ]
  end

  (...)

end
```

This is somewhat explained in a [chapter of the Mix & OTP Getting Started Guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks-and-configuration.html#application-environment-and-configuration).

---

You can use the same trick to explicitly import the dependency's configuration by adding this line to `hello_app/config/config.exs`:

```
import_config "../../world_app/config/config.exs"
```

Comment: This has helped me very much, thank you **The more you know**

Answer (score 0):

As update to Zoltán answer, if you are using [Config](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#import_config/1) instead of [Mix.Config](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Config.html) in [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#module-migrating-from-use-mix-config) is stated:

> Make sure your import_config/1 calls do not have a wildcard character.
>   If so, you need to perform the wildcard lookup manually. For example,
>   if you did:

```
import_config "../apps/*/config/config.exs"
```

> It has to be replaced by:

```
for config <- "../apps/*/config/config.exs" |> Path.expand(__DIR__) |> Path.wildcard() do
      import_config config
    end
```